# Postgres Recursive query + group by + join in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, recursion, sql

My Requirement is to write a sql query to get the sub-region wise (fault)events count that occurred for the managedobjects. My database is postgres 8.4. Let me explain using the table structure.

My tables in django:
Managedobject:

```
class Managedobject(models.Model):
   name                = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
   iscontainer         = models.BooleanField(default=False,)
   parentkey           = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
```

Event Table:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    Name        = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'))
    foid        = models.ForeignKey(Managedobject)
```

Managedobject Records:

```
NOC
   Chennai
      MO_1
      MO_2
      MO_3
   Mumbai
      MO_4
      MO_5
      MO_6
   Delhi
   Bangalore
IP
   Calcutta
   Cochin
```

Events Records:

```
event1 MO_1
event2 MO_2
event3 MO_3
event4 MO_5
event5 MO_6
```

Now I need to get the events count for all the sub-regions. For example,

```
for NOC region:
  Chennai - 3
  Mumbai - 2
  Delhi - 0
  Bangalore - 0
```

So far I am able to get the result in two different queries.

1. Get the subregions.

   ```
   select id from managedobject where iscontainer = True and parentkey = 3489
   ```
2. For each of the region (using for loop), get the count as follows:

   ```
   SELECT count(*) 
   from event ev 
   WHERE ev.foid 
   IN (
       WITH RECURSIVE q AS (
           SELECT h 
           FROM managedobject h 
           WHERE parentkey = 3489 
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT hi 
           FROM q 
           JOIN managedobject hi 
           ON hi.parentkey = (q.h).id 
       ) 
       SELECT (q.h).id FROM q
   )
   ```

Please help to combine the queries to make it a single query and for getting the top 5 regions. Since the query is difficult in django, I am going for a raw sql query.

Comment: do you need that `iscontainer` field? if parentkey = None then the object isn't a container and if the Managedobject has a parentkey, then it is a container?

Comment: @krieger. Thanks for the effort. Here container has got a different meaning. The parent/child relationship level goes endless in Managedobject table. If the record is marked as container, it is a logical entity just added for grouping. Even Record MO_1 can have child MO_11 but it is not a container as it represents a physical entity.

Comment: ohhh i see, I misread your initial question. I'll give this another look in a bit. sorry about that. I thought the MO_1 were the events, they are just which managedobject the events were related too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE q AS ( 
  SELECT  h, 
          1 AS level, 
          id AS ckey, 
          displayname as dname 
  FROM managedobject h 
  WHERE parentkey = 3489  
    and logicalnode=True 

 UNION ALL 

 SELECT  hi, 
         q.level + 1 AS level, 
         ckey, 
         dname 
 FROM q 
   JOIN managedobject hi ON hi.parentkey = (q.h).id 
) 
SELECT count(ckey) as ccount, 
       ckey, 
       dname 
FROM q 
  JOIN event as ev on ev.foid_id = (q.h).id 
GROUP BY ckey, dname 
ORDER BY ccount DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: What is this expression: `ev.foid_id = (q.h).id` doing? Is that a typo?

Comment: No, It is a running query. In Django, foreignkey field will be appended with "_id". In postgres recursive query, you have to access the field as "(q.h).id".

Comment: I have never seen that syntax with a recursive CTE. I'd say `q.id` should be enough for the inner query. The outer should probably use `q.ckey`